# How does python "know" what to do with the "in" keyword?

Tags: python

I'm a bit bewildered by the "in" keyword in python.

If I take a sample list of tuples:

```
data = [
    (5, 1, 9.8385465),
    (10, 1, 8.2087544),
    (15, 1, 7.8788187),
    (20, 1, 7.5751283)
]
```

I can do two different "for - in" loops and get different results:

```
for G,W,V in data:
    print G,W,V
```

This prints each set of values on a line, e.g. `5, 1, 9.8385465`

```
for i in data:
    print i
```

This prints the whole tuple, e.g. `(5, 1, 9.8385465)`

How does python "know" that by providing one variable I want to assign the tuple to a variable, and that by providing three variables I want to assign each value from the tuple to one of those variables?

Comment: This really doesn't strike me as all that strange. How does it know what to do with these two non-`for` loop assignments: `x = (1,2,3)` and `a,b,c = (1,2,3)`? It's just written into the parser/runtime.

Comment: Before this I didn't know I could do that either :) Python is new to me and I've been writing in C and Java until now.

Comment: @DanielB. More than that, you can do `a, (b, c) = (1, (2, 3))`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

According to [the `for` compound statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> Each item in turn is assigned to the target list using the standard
>   rules for assignments...

Those *"standard rules"* are in [the assignment statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), specifically:

> Assignment of an object to a target list is recursively defined as
>   follows.
>
> - If the target list is a single target: The object is assigned to that target.
> - If the target list is a comma-separated list of targets: The object must be an iterable with the same number of items as there are targets
>     in the target list, and the items are assigned, from left to right, to
>     the corresponding targets.

So this different behaviour, depending on whether you assign to a single target or a list of targets, is baked right into Python's fundamentals, and applies wherever assignment is used.

Answer (score 23):

This isn't really a feature of the `in` keyword, but of the Python language.  The same works with assignment.

```
x = (1, 2, 3)
print(x)
>>> (1, 2, 3)

a, b, c = (1, 2, 3)
print(a)
>>> 1
print(b)
>>> 2
print(c)
>>> 3
```

So to answer your question, it's more that Python knows what to do with assignments when you either:

- assign a tuple to a variable, or
- assign a tuple to a number of variables equal to the number of items in the tuple

Answer (score 12):

It's called [tuple unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), and has nothing to do with the `in` keyword.

The `for` loop returns the single thing (a `tuple` in this case), and then that `tuple` gets assigned -- to a single item in the second case, or multiple items in the first case.

If you try specifying the incorrect number of variables:

```
for G,W in data:
    print G,W

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: Isn't it still unpacking as indicated by the error, "Too many values to unpack?"

Comment: @RiaD: Changed the link.

Answer (score 3):

Iterators notionally return a single item (the `for a in b` syntax).

The compiler knows that if you specify more than one thing for `a` that the one returned value must itself be iterable and contain the same number of items as your list of variables. It would throw a runtime error if you had `for a, b in c` and the elements of `c` did not contain exactly two items.

So in short it "knew" because that is what you told it. It will explode at runtime if you lied ...

Comment: Meaning that if I said, say, a,b = (1,2,3) then it'd throw an exception?

Comment: @DanielB. - You can try `a,b = (1,2,3)` in an interpreter and see the results yourself. Try other things as well, such as `a,b,c,d = 1,2,3` and `a, *b = 1,2,3`.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the `a, *b = 1,2,3` only works in Python3.